# Using < in CM annotation truncates the message

Tags: bug, moderator-tools

I tried to send a message to the CMs that started with:

> I'm afraid this user is < 13 years old; see [...]

but in the user history this message shows up as:

[image: truncated CM contact entry]

Note that the message is cut off at the `<`. I don't know if the whole message was emailed out to the CMs or if the message was truncated before that point.

Comment: Most likely they forgot to encode, so it's only a display bug. Can you inspect the element and see if the contents are there?

Comment: Devs have been summoned. They'll get this fixed, but I think we're going to need another chicken.

Comment: @Tim will Blue Footed Booby of the Galapagos Islands suffice? You already got one.... :D

Comment: I wonder what happens in your put in `<script ...` in the comment :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard: nope, I already did and the remainder of the message is not there.

Comment: @Pat hey, don't give him idea how to steal Tim's cookie!

Comment: @MartijnPieters well, so it's probably worse than I thought. Hopefully Tim summon will be answered shortly and it will be fixed.

Comment: @PatrickHofman I just made sure that that's not a problem. This isn't a security issue (in fact, we're probably just sanitizing *too much*, not too little)

Comment: ^ So Tim can keep his cookie @Sha. Don't worry :)

Comment: Did someone say cookie? I like cookies.

Comment: @TimPost http://picchore.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/01/delete-cookies-comic.jpg

Comment: I'm confused: Are you confessing that sock-puppet is yours?

Comment: I don't think cookies would taste very good with socks.

Comment: @TimPost That has in fact [been confirmed](http://imgur.com/a/mpXut).

Comment: @TimPost: here, have a [stability chicken](https://media.giphy.com/media/7YPMvy4LHmZJ6/giphy.gif).

Comment: @MartijnPieters Flagged for the RSPCA, Twisting Birds unit.